# How to solve the Riccati equation of a special type?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following ODE:
$$
y'=\frac{y^2}{2x}-\frac{1}{2}.
$$
It's a special case of Riccati equation:
$$
y'=f(x)+g(x)y+h(x)y^2,
$$
but in a special form with zero $g(x)$ and constant $f(x)$. As far as I understand, there is no (standard, elementary) general way to solve Riccati equations, unless we find its partial solution. So the question is: how to find a partial solution of this equation and are there any other ways to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'=\frac{y^2}{2x}-\frac{1}{2}$$
The usual change of function to solve this Riccati ODE is :
$$y=-2x\frac{u'}{u}$$
$$y'=-2\frac{u'}{u}-2x\frac{u''}{u}+2x\frac{(u')^2}{u^2}=\frac{\left(-2x\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2}{2x}-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$-2\frac{u'}{u}-2x\frac{u''}{u}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$u''+\frac{1}{x}u'-\frac{1}{4x}u=0$$
This is a Bessel equation which solution is :
$$u=c_1I_0(\sqrt{x})+c_2K_0(\sqrt{x})$$
$I_0$ and $K_0$ are the modified Bessel functions of first and second kind.
$$y=-\sqrt{x}\:\frac{c_1I_1(\sqrt{x})-c_2K_1(\sqrt{x})}{c_1I_0(\sqrt{x})+c_2K_0(\sqrt{x})}$$
Remember : The usual way to solve a Riccati ODE when one cannot guess a particular solution consists in transforming the Riccati ODE into a second order linear ODE. This is because a second order linear ODE is often easier to solve that a non-linear first order ODE.